# Is there a convention for marking a pointer as to-const in Go?

Tags: go, pointers, struct

If I am declaring a function or channel that returns a struct, I may want to return it by pointer for efficiency but not want clients messing about with its content. In the absence of the ability to express that in the language, is there some common convention for indicating "please don't modify it"? Is it simply that client should always assume that unless clearly told otherwise, in the spirit of "share memory by communicating"? If that is the case, that raises the question how to indicate mutability.

Note I am not asking for opinions on how any one person might do it, whether it is worth it in any given situation or what other mechanisms the language has. I am asking if there is any generally accepted community-standard convention to indicate these things, in the same way that Go has clear conventions for [how to document functions](https://blog.golang.org/godoc)

Assume the struct is big enough for the difference to matter in context, and of course that benchmarking has shown that.

As noted in comments, clearly returning an encapsulated struct with perhaps a read only interface would be preferable, but I am re-using existing structs and refactoring every other use of them would be a major undertaking that I do not wish to embark on right now.

Comment: If you don't want something to be modified, then make it a struct with unexported fields. Then it _can't_ be modified.

Comment: Have you confirmed that a pointer makes this more efficient? The structure needs to be fairly large and heavily copied to make any noticeable difference. In general, you document the type's usage and have to expect that other programmers read the documentation.

Comment: Unexported fields + interface would be the best choice of course, but that's not a viable refactoring right now in the motivating example.

Comment: "I may want to return it by pointer for efficiency" If, and only if this is the actual, real bottleneck of application (and it isn't, I guarantee) return a pointer. Could you explain why you think (note that this is common!) returning (or passing) a pointer would be "more efficient"? I'm really curious. For any non-pathological (read: handcrafted to show the converse) struct passing a pointer or the struct value doesn't matter.

Comment: I didn't downvote this but I feel like this question can be even better with a concrete example. Like in what situation would you have to hesitate using unexported fields / using values instead of pointers

Comment: @volker OK , here's a funny thing. I benchmarked my API in pointer and value variants, decided it was worth changing and deleted the benchmark. I just recreated it to post this and the two versions are basically indistinguishable. Interesting. So fair enough, in this case it's probably not making a difference.

Comment: Note also that you don't have to go all-in with either pointer or struct value. You also have the option of copying the value *once* and returning a pointer to the copy. Then callers can modify the value without affecting you, but still don't have to allocate and copy large structs everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the absence of the ability to express that in the language, is there some common convention for indicating "please don't modify it"?

No, there is not.

As noted in the comments, what you may do is use unexported fields which can't be accessed outside of the declaring package. If you do need to allow read-only access to some fields, you may add exported methods returning those values.

Also note that using pointers solely for efficiency is *overrated*. Often using small or medium structs without pointers are just as (if not better) performant. In the light of this, you may just return a non-pointer struct value which will be a copy, naturally "shielding" the original struct value from modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:  pointer to const: No.
Secondly: Share memory by communicating: **Send a copy**.

Sice you need to protect your content:

1. At the package level: Use **Exported** and **unexported** values and methods.
2. There is a special solution for protecting inside a package too, see this `private struct`, which a programmer can **not** touch it outside of the `private()` function:

```
type private struct {
        buf   []byte
        state int
    }
```

Try this [example](https://play.golang.org/p/mPRnUxN9sTz):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    next := private() // a copy of desired content

    fmt.Println(next()) // [1 0]
    fmt.Println(next()) // [1 1]
    fmt.Println(next()) // [2 1]
}

func private() func() []byte {
    type private struct {
        buf   []byte
        state int
    }
    big := new(private)
    big.buf = make([]byte, 2) // e.g. big buf

    return func() []byte {
        big.buf[big.state]++ // for example
        big.state++
        if big.state >= len(big.buf) {
            big.state = 0
        }
        buf := make([]byte, len(big.buf))
        copy(buf, big.buf)
        return buf
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea about returning a closure, but defining and using the `private` type in your `private()` function has no use, it actually makes it more complicated compared to a solution without that type: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ngHYS2wlSO1)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This example is just for demonstration purpose, and yes we can make it more [simple](https://play.golang.org/p/YRVSLRC9ODL).